# MapBox iOS SDK within your own Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mapbox

I downloaded MapBox example from github using the following 
         git clone --recursive https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example.git

Which downloaded it including all dependencies. Now I'm trying to create a separate project and include MapBox DSK as it was in that example. I tried creating workspace then creating a single view project then add new file and select .xcodepro for the MapBox DSK but didn't work when I tried importing `MapBox.h` file. I never tried importing 3rd parties API before and a bit not sure how I can do that correctly. Any Idea how I can accomplish that ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Just try:

```
 #import <Mapbox/Mapbox.h>
```

instead of just importing Mapbox.h as suggested here:
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/ios-sdk-framework

Answer (score 2):

You simply drag the Mapbox-ios-sdk project file from Finder to the files pane in Xcode.

And then click the project in Xcode files pane, Target-->Build Settings. Search for "User Header Search Paths". Specify where the MapBox sdk is located.

What I do is I put the MapBox-iOS-sdk in my project directory. And I set the path as `$(SRCROOT)` and make sure to set it as recursive.

While you're at it also make sure -ObjC and -all_load are set in Other linker flags.

That only helps you reference the .h files, to link, also under Build Setting, Link Binary with Libraries you need libMapBox.a.

If there is a MapBox.bundle (as in the latest development branch) in the group and files pane, you want to drag that into Target->Build phases->Copy bundle resources as well. (The add button doesn't work for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to look at [mapbox-ios-example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-example) provided by MapBox and try to replicate all dependencies into your own project.

Comment: i did find the .framework file for MapBox buried somewhere in there site so i used it. I still would love to give it a try later. thanks for the reply though

Comment: Can you give me a link? I would like to see it too :).

Comment: Martin, i will look for it and post the link

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I still have the problem of Mapbox.h file not found. Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: Try #import "Mapbox.h", not #import <Mapbox/Mapbox.h>. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I did it like it was explained here: http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#binary.

Not messing around with git, just dragging things into your project, easy!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is he couldn't find a specific 'file' that was titled "MapBox.Framework" inside the folder of resources downloaded from Map Box, however what you actually need to do is copy that whole folder, which is titled "MapBox.Framework" into the frameworks section. I think the confusion was that the main folder that needs to be copied doesn't look like the yellow framework icon until you copy that folder into Xcode's frameworks section.