# Adding Mapbox to iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, mapbox

So, ... I went through the tutorial, using the binary steps to go through this.
I went through some answers here and that's where it gets confusing as there are even more variations on which linker flags to add and header paths, etc.
I tried these: [MapBox iOS SDK within your own Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983260/mapbox-ios-sdk-within-your-own-xcode) no help.
The project doesn't find the classes/headers.

The only project I found that works is their sample XCode project. I replicated all those dependencies, no luck.

I could put all my code into the iOS example, but it over a year old and not indicated to include the latest version 1.6.1.

I hate cocoapods as they add too much setting up into the project and if I get the same issue with other 3rd party frameworks, (there's plenty ill documented out there) how woudl I add that?

So, anyone else having those issues of the Mapbox tutorial not working and what was your solution?